# Elastic data transfer from server 1 (in recovery mode) to 2

Tags: ubuntu, backup, snapshot, elasticsearch-5

I have **server 1** in recovery mode so it cannot take elastic snapshot. **Server 2** is having elastic running. Both servers are connected to the internet but not to the cluster.

What if I copy data form `/var/lib/elasticsearch/` of **server 1** (which is in rescue mode) to **server 2**?

In this case, will elastic of **server 2** be able to recognize data copied from **server 1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

It works I tried it on scaleway for full backup of elasticsearch without making snapshot.

I transferred data of **/var/lib/elasticsearch/node/0** from **server 1** to **server 2** on the same location.
On successful restart of elasticsearch, I can see healthy indexes on **server 2**

Comment: nice one @Vishvendra Singh